# How to inject $routeProvider in Angular spec

Tags: angularjs, rspec

When passing this function that includes $routeProvider into a module definition, how do you mock/inject it properly in spec?

**module.js**

```
angular.module('myModule', [
  // Without the function($routeProvider) below the test passes. With it, it fails.
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/some/url/:id', {templateUrl: 'template.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  }
])
```

**myModuleCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('myModuleCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.testMethod = function () {
        alert('Test Me!');
      }
    }
  ]);
```

**myModuleCtrl.spec.js**

```
describe('myModuleCtrl', function () {
  var controller;
  var $scope;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(function () {
    $scope = {};
  });
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    controller = $controller('myModuleCtrl', {'$scope': $scope});
  }));

  describe('when doing stuff', function() {
    it('does other stuff', function() {
      $scope.testMethod();
    });
  });
});
```

As commented in module.js, without the $routeProvider line the spec passes. With it, it fails with the following message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function ($routeProvider) due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

What needs to be done in the spec file to get this module to load (including the $routeProvider)?

Comment: Angular router is a separate module. Did you include it in your source code? https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ngRoute

Comment: $routeProvider needs to be in a config() block. The syntax in module.js of your module definition is incorrect.

Comment: @PeterJ.Hart Aside from the spec, I inherited this code, and it works as is. As I understand it, the syntax is a shorthand for an equivalent config() block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module should have injected dependency ngRoute

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])
```

Samething should be there for the test,

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule',['ngRoute']));
```

Comment: Except that it needs to be `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule','ngRoute'));`